# Is there any reward in Islam for looking after cats?

Tags: reward, helping, cats

Salaam alaikum!

**Background:**

My whole life is falling apart, long story short I reverted to islam about 4 years ago.

About 3 years ago I met my husband, we moved into my husband's auntie's house, however we are being forced to move into downstairs rooms (not sure permenantly) The room is disgusting (mold, cracks on the wall, peeling wallpaper) and freezing cold due to there being patio doors that aren't sealed properly.

There is major renovation going on in that house meaning we and our two cats have nowhere to stay.

Alhamdulliah that my husband's family are letting us crash at there house but they can't keep our cats as they have a cat breeding business.

My non Muslim parents have kept them for 3 days and now are asking us to take them back, nothing can persuade them. No one we know will take them. So now I have to keep them in my house In the kitchen with building work going on.

So now everyday I'm going to have to walk 2 miles from my in-laws house to my house, to feed them, play with the and cuddle them. It will be difficult as I'm not mentally too well.

**Question:**

I am really suffering and I'm in need of Islamic motivation.

I'd like to know is there any reward for my efforts in looking after my cats? Perhaps if there was I'd feel better and be more motivated to do it.

Comment: Maybe you can ask at [pets.SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) for options on dealing with this, e.g. there might be places which will take care of your pets for a fee. There is reward for kindness to anything (https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/40).

Answer (score 3):

In Islamic tradition, cats are admired for their cleanliness. They are thought to be ritually clean, thus they are allowed to enter homes and mosques.
Yes! There are rewards for taking care of cats or any other Allah creation.

The Prophet (ﷺ) said:

> The Compassionate One has mercy on those who are merciful. If you show mercy to those who are on the earth, He Who is in the heaven will show mercy to you. [Sunan Abi Dawud 4941]

Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said:

> > "While a man was walking on a road. he became very thirsty. Then he came across a well, got down into it, drank (of its water) and then came out. Meanwhile he saw a dog panting and licking mud because of excessive thirst. The man said to himself "This dog is suffering from the same state of thirst as I did." **So he went down the well (again) and filled his shoe (with water) and held it in his mouth and watered the dog. Allah thanked him for that deed and forgave him."**
>
> The people asked:
>
> > "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Is there a reward for us in serving the animals?"
>
> He said
>
> > "(Yes) There is a reward for serving any animate (living being) ."
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari 6009]

It was narrated that ‘Abdullah ibn Raafi‘ said:

> > I said to Abu Hurayrah: Why do you have the kunyah of Abu Hurayrah?
>
> > He said: I used to tend my family’s sheep, and I had a small kitten (hurayrah) that I used to put in a tree at night, then during the day I would take it with me and play with it. Hence they called me Abu Hurayrah (“father of the kitten”).
>
> Narrated by at-Tirmidhi (3840); classed as hasan by al-Haafiz in al-Isaabah (13/30).

One should not captivate any animal and give it any harm as Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said:

> "A woman was tortured and was put in Hell because of a cat which she had kept locked till it died of hunger."

One should not keep any pet if they are going through tough times or any struggle's of life, and can't properly feed pets as Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) further said :

> (Allah knows better) Allah said (to the woman), 'You neither fed it nor watered when you locked it up, nor did you set it free to eat the vermin of the earth.'

Rather one should set it free, or give it to any trusty petshop or to anyone willing to keep that animal. *(Cats and Dogs can be sold according to majority of scholars)*.

Answer (score -1):

Imam sadiq said: cat can be one of member of family. if cat drink water, Muslim can do Wudu by that water.[ref](https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa9085)

Comment: This answer is not useful, because it doesn't answer the question **" Is there any reward in Islam for looking after cats? "**. The permissibility of keeping cats was not inquired by the questionnaire, though it may be better of as a side information.